# How to get row update count in a DB2 update query in node.js?

Tags: node.js, db2, rowcount, ibm-db2

I am trying to execute an update statement in node.js on DB2 database. The update operation works but I don't know how to get the count of updated records in DB2 after query execution. Any help will be appreciated.
Below is my code:

```
conn.beginTransaction(function (err) {
if (err) {
//could not begin a transaction for some reason. 
console.log(err);
return conn.closeSync();
}
var stmt = ("Update tableA set col1='abc' where col2='xyz'");
var result = conn.querySync(stmt);
conn.commitTransaction(function (err){
if (err) {
console.log(err);
return conn.closeSync();
}
});
console.log('Rows affected :: '+ result.numRows());
});
```

Comment: I recommend to ask in this forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-ibm_db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NPM documentation seems a bit incomplete. For DML statements you probably should use `ODBCStatement.executeNonQuerySync()`, which, [according to the source code (line 413)](https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/blob/master/src/odbc_statement.cpp), returns the number of affected rows.

If you're working with a recent version of DB2 for LUW, as an alternative you can wrap your `UPDATE` in a *data change table* reference:

```
var stmt = ("select count(*) from final table (" + 
            "Update tableA set col1='abc' where col2='xyz'"+
            ")");
var result = conn.querySync(stmt);
```

`result` will contain the number of affected rows.